# Rename pandas column iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I have several columns named the same in a data frame.  How can I rename the below `normal` and `KIRC` to `normal_1`, `normal_2`, `KIRC_1`, `KIRC_2`?

import pandas as pd

```
gene_exp.columns = gene_exp.iloc[-1]
gene_exp = gene_exp.iloc[:-1]
gene_exp

# Append "_[number]" 
c = pd.Series(gene_exp.columns)
for dup in gene_exp.columns[gene_exp.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]: 
    c[df.columns.get_loc(dup)] = ([dup + '_' + str(d_idx) 
                                     if d_idx != 0 
                                     else dup 
                                     for d_idx in range(gene_exp.columns.get_loc(dup).sum())]
                                    )
gene_exp
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'KIRC'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/3403075751.py in <module>
      5                                      if d_idx != 0
      6                                      else dup
----> 7                                      for d_idx in range(gene_exp.columns.get_loc(dup).sum())]
      8                                     )
      9 gene_exp

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'KIRC'
```

Sample data

|  | Gene | NAME | KIRC | normal | normal | KIRC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL | MNO | PQR |
| 1 | STU | VWX | YZ | ABC | DEF | GHI |

Desired output:

|  | Gene | NAME | KIRC_1 | normal_1 | normal_2 | KIRC_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | DEF | GHI | JKL | MNO | PQR |
| 1 | STU | VWX | YZ | ABC | DEF | GHI |

Comment: Posted an answer. Did it worked for you?

Comment: As I mentioned below the accepted answer, please review the performance impacts of that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# set Gene and Name as Index, as we don't need these renamed
df.set_index(['Gene','NAME'], inplace=True)

# create a dataframe from the columns
df2=pd.DataFrame(df.columns.values, columns=['col'])

# create new columns by counting repeated names and adding 1 to count
# assign columns to the dataframe
df.columns=df2['col']+ '_' +(df2.groupby('col').cumcount()+1).astype(str)

# reset index
out=df.reset_index()
```

OR

```
# we just need to manipulate the columns by reindexing
# so creating a temporary DF helps with the performance 

# create a temp DF
df_cols=df.head()


# SAME AS ABOVE SOLUTION, EXCEPT DF REPLACE WITH DF_COLUMNS
df_cols.set_index(['Gene','NAME'], inplace=True)

# create a dataframe from the columns
df2=pd.DataFrame(df_cols.columns.values, columns=['col'])
# create new columns by counting repeated names and adding 1 to count
# assign columns to the dataframe
df_cols.columns=df2['col']+ '_' +(df2.groupby('col').cumcount()+1).astype(str)
df_cols.reset_index(inplace=True)


# Update the columns in DF
df.columns = df_cols.columns
df
```

```
   Gene     NAME    KIRC_1  normal_1    normal_2    KIRC_2
0   ABC     DEF     GHI          JKL         MNO       PQR
1   STU     VWX     YZ           ABC        DEF        GHI
```

Comment: This'll work but it seems like there would be a performance impact on setting / resetting the index and also doing a groupby as part of the process?

Comment: @AllanElder, you made a very valid point. I updated the solution with an alternate to address the performance concerns. Thanks for bringing it up. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your starting dataset, but this should do what you want - you don't look like you're assigning the columns back to the dataframe in your code, and you're not assigning the incrementer to dup if it is 0

```
data = {"Gene": "ABC", "NAME": "DEF", "KIRC": "GHI", "normal": "MNO"}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([data])
df = pd.concat([df, df[["KIRC", "normal"]]], axis=1)
cols = pd.Series(df.columns)
for dup in df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]:
    cols[df.columns.get_loc(dup)] = ([dup + '_' + str(d_idx+1)
                                     for d_idx in range(df.columns.get_loc(dup).sum())]
                                    )
df.columns = cols
print(df)
```